# Type in inline assembly

Tags: inline-assembly

In some code I was writing, I had the following line:

__asm mov [ebp-24], 0

...from which the compiler generated
mov BYTE PTR [ebp-24], 0

Is there any way I can make it generate
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-24], 0
instead?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your assembler (you didn't state what you are using), try:

```
mov dword ptr [ebp-24], 0
```

or

```
movl [ebp-24], 0
```

Comment: ...The first actually worked. I could swear that I had tried that and it had not allowed it. Must have made a typo the first time.
Thanks!